# XSL transformation for script tag

Tags: xslt

I have an xsl file that takes html embedded within xml and transforms it to html. I did not write this and I don't know a lick of xsl but I have to make this work as it's a small part of my work item.

I have found a bug that renders any empty `<script>` tags with the tag that is directly below it. Here's an example...

This:

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”…”></script>
<p>…</p>
```

Renders as this...

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”…”><p>…</p></script>
```

Here is the existing xsl...

```
<xsl:template match="script">
    <script>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </script>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's the whole xsl file. **NOTE:** I've changed the script transformation in trying some fixes out. Still getting the same bug...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="p">
    <p>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="script">
    <xsl:element name="script">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="option">
    <option>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </option>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="select">
    <select>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </select>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
    <object>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </object>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="param">
    <param>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </param>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="label">
    <label>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </label>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <input>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </input>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="textarea">
    <textarea>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </textarea>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="nbsp">
&#160;
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="noscript">
    <xsl:element name="noscript">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <a>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="href">
            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:apply-templates select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="title">
            <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:apply-templates select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="onclick">
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick"><xsl:apply-templates select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:apply-templates />

    </a>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="strong">
    <strong>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </strong>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span">
        <span>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(.) > 0">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul">
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="u">
    <u><xsl:apply-templates /></u>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ol">
    <ol><xsl:apply-templates /></ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li">
    <li>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br">
  <br>  
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </br>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
    <h1>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </h1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h2">
    <h2>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </h2>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h3">
    <h3><xsl:apply-templates /></h3>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h4">
    <h4><xsl:apply-templates /></h4>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h5">
    <h5><xsl:apply-templates /></h5>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="blockquote">
    <blockquote>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
  </blockquote>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="img">
    <img>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </img>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i">
    <xsl:element name="i">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(.) > 0">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="em">
    <xsl:element name="em">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(.) > 0 or node()">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="div">

    <xsl:if test="@class or @id or @style or string-length(.) > 0 or node()">

        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />             
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>         

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(.) > 0 or node()">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fieldset">

    <xsl:if test="@class or @id or @style or string-length(.) > 0 or node()">

        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(.) > 0 or node()">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="legend">

    <xsl:if test="@class or @id or @style or string-length(.) > 0 or node()">

        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(.) > 0 or node()">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sup">
    <sup>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </sup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="font">
    <font>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </font>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody">
    <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </tbody>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr">
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td">
    <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <b>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </b>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hr">
    <hr>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </hr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your XSLT snippet, so it possible the problem lies elsewhere. Are you sure there isn't another template in the XSLT that might match the **script** element? Is is possible to post the full XSLT file if it is not too big?

Comment: It's pretty big, but it's the only place where "script" is referenced.

Comment: Is there possible a more 'generic' template that is matching it? One way to check could be to output a 'test' element within the script tag. For example...... `<script><xsl:apply-templates /><test /></script>` and then see if that appears in the output.

Comment: @TimC Ok, trying that now, thanks

Comment: I'll post the whole xsl file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't actually fix your problem (I think), but am giving it as an answer as it is too long to fit in a comment....

There is rather a lot of repitition in the XSLT. Many of the templates seem to follow the same pattern. For example

```
<xsl:template match="h1"> 
    <h1> 
        <xsl:for-each select="@*"> 
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </h1> 
</xsl:template>
```

All this is doing is making a copy of the **h1** element in this case, including its attributes, and then the child elements.

There is no need to have so many separate templates in this case. There can be a generic template to handle such cases. In fact, what is needed is the common XSLT design pattern known as the 'Identity Transform'

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On its own, it will copy your XML as is, without making any changs. You only need to extend it with other templates where you need to do other processing rather than just output an element unchanged (For example, in the template for **span** there is extra processing to add a style attribute). The XSLT will give priority to more specific template matches (one where you match a specific name) over the generic one shown above.

So, I would recommend removing the majority of specific templates in the XSLT, including the ones matching **script** and **p** and just add the generic template match of the identity transform instead. In fact, you might want to start with the basic identity transform, check that works, and add one template at a time for each case where you need some extra processing.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd make sure that the `script` template is the one producing the output. To check, you could add a dummy `class` attribute to the opening `<script>` tag.

Also try removing `<xsl:apply-templates />` from the template so it looks like this;

```
<xsl:template match="script">
    <script class="dummy">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </script>
</xsl:template>
```